# Workarounds for using custom methods/extension methods in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I have defined a GenericRepository class which does the db interaction.

```
 protected GenericRepository rep = new GenericRepository();
```

And in my BLL classes, I can query the db like:

```
public List<Album> GetVisibleAlbums(int accessLevel)
{
    return rep.Find<Album>(a => a.AccessLevel.BinaryAnd(accessLevel)).ToList();  
}
```

BinaryAnd is an extension method which checks two int values bit by bit. e.g. `AccessLevel=5` => `AccessLevel.BinaryAnd(5)` and `AccessLevel.binaryAnd(1)` both return true.

However I cannot use this extension method in my LINQ queries. I get a runtime error as follows:
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean BinaryAnd(System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Also tried changing it to a custom method but no luck. What are the workarounds?

Should I get all the albums and then iterate them through a foreach loop and pick those which match the AccessLevels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use the [core extension methods and CLR methods defined for your EF provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) when using Entity Framework and queries on `IQueryable<T>`.  This is because the query is translated directly to SQL code and run on the server.

You can stream the entire collection (using `.ToEnumerable()`) then query this locally, or convert this to a method that is translatable directly to SQL by your provider.

That being said, [basic bitwise operations are supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx):

> The bitwise AND, OR, NOT, and XOR operators are also mapped to canonical functions when the operand is a numeric type.

So, if you rewrite this to not use a method, and just do the bitwise operation on the value directly, it should work as needed.  Try something like the following:

```
public List<Album> GetVisibleAlbums(int accessLevel)
{
    return rep.Find<Album>(a => (a.AccessLevel & accessLevel > 0)).ToList();  
}
```

(I'm not sure exactly how your current extension method works - the above would check to see if any of the flags come back true, which seems to match your statement...)

Comment: Thanks Reed. Guess that's the only way.

Comment: @Kamyar: It should just be a matter of not using the extension method, and putting the actual code in the query - see my edit.

Answer (score 10):

I realize this already has an accepted answer, I just thought I'd post this in case someone wanted to try writing a LINQ expression interceptor.

So... here is what I did to make translatable custom extension methods: [Code Sample](http://pastebin.com/4fMjaCMV)

I don't believe this to be a finished solution, but it should hopefully provide a good starting point for anyone brave enough to see it through to completion.

Comment: I found that in the extension method `.Where(p=> p.Key == 25)` gives a error about p being unbound.  So I had to declare the lambda like this `Expression<Func<PropertyHistory, bool>> exp = (p) => p.Key ==25;` and then use it in `.Where(exp)`.  Considering the reusability of the extension, it is still great.  There is an open bounty here if you want to post your answer.  I would really appreciate you posting a comment if you make updates to your code.  This is worthy of a codeplex project I think.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826275/iqueryable-extension-method-for-linq2entities

Comment: @AaronLS I did indeed update it. I wanted to add support for compiled queries and custom extension method to expression translations. Not sure if it's a good solution yet, I was just trying stuff out. You can check it out here: [Code](http://pastebin.com/G3QXS1gb)

Comment: This is super awesome, you should put it in nuget

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to change the linq query just before EF translates it to SQL, at that moment you'd have to translate your ''foreign'' method into a construct translatable by EF.

See an previous question of mine [How to wrap Entity Framework to intercept the LINQ expression just before execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839901/how-to-wrap-entity-framework-to-intercept-the-linq-expression-just-before-executi) and mine [EFWrappableFields extension](https://github.com/DavyLandman/EFWrappableFields) which does just this for wrapped fields.