# Entity Framework: Loading Filtered Collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

Given the next model

```
public class Author{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Book> GetGoodBooks(){
        return Books.Where(n => n.Rating > 6)
    }
}

public class Book{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set;}
}
```

I need to retrieve (**in only one query**) all the authors with all their good books (using **GetGoodBooks()**). So i do the next:

```
IQueryable<Author> query = from author in repository.ListAll<Author>() // it returns an IQueryable<Author>
                           select new Author() {
                               author.Id,
                               author.Name,
                               Books = author.GetGoodBooks() // it throws an exception
                           };

var list = query.ToList();
```

As you know, it will throw an exception because of using the method **GetGoodBooks()** within the Linq to Entities.

So, i know that i can make it works replacing the method for Linq clause like this:

```
IQueryable<Author> query = from author in repository.ListAll<Author>() // it returns an IQueryable<Author>
                           select new Author() {
                               author.Id,
                               author.Name,
                               Books = author.Books.Where(n => n.Rating > 6)
                           };

var list = query.ToList();
```

It works ok, but i want to use the author's interface i've designed!

Do you know any way i can do this maintaining the object design?

Answer (score 0):

Possible dublicate [Workarounds for using custom methods/extension methods in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867100/workarounds-for-using-custom-methods-extension-methods-in-linq-to-entities) I had the same ideas when started working with EF