# Can LINQ-To-Entities be expanded?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

In general, If I create an extension method that acts on an entity:

```
public static MyEntity Foo(this MyEntity entity)
{
  // do something to the entity
}
```

One cannot directly use this in a projection from Linq-To-Entities such as follows:

```
var result = myContext.MyEntities.Select(x=> x.Foo());
```

Doing so yields an error such as:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'Foo(MyEntity)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

I fully understand why this error occurs.  My question is this:  If I can provide an implementation of Foo that uses an expression tree, is there some way that I can add Foo to the operations that LINQ-to-entities understands?  And if so - how?

---

Note:  I can certainly convert it to a list like this:

```
var result = myContext.MyEntities.ToList().Select(x=> x.Foo());
```

And it doesn't error.  But I no longer have an IQueryable.  I have an IEnumerable.  If I were to use it like this:

```
var result = myContext.MyEntities.ToList().Select(x=> x.Foo()).First();
```

I would end up fetching ALL entities before taking the top one and discarding the rest - which would be horrible for performance.

Comment: You can write your own IQueryProvider, wrap EF's query provider, recognize your expression that calls Foo, and feed EF a chain of equivalent expressions that it can translate to the language of the backing store (e.g. SQL). But that's not much fun, and it's not universal. What does `Foo` do, anyway?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what it does, that's why I just called it Foo.  I have a few different needs for stuff like this and was really just looking for the hooks.  I like your idea about wrapping the EF query provider.  Can you provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: See: [How to wrap Entity Framework to intercept the LINQ expression just before execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839901/how-to-wrap-entity-framework-to-intercept-the-linq-expression-just-before-execut)

Comment: @MattJohnson What `Foo` does matters a lot, as your ability to push the logic into the underlying data store depends on it. Ultimately your implementation would either have `Foo`'s logic executed in RDBMS, or pull everything into memory and run `Foo` inside CLR (essentially, resorting to the same code path as with `ToLost` in your example). However, general, EF gives you lots of very useful extension points that you should consider before going for your own IQueryProvider wrapper.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I see what you are getting at.  Can you elaborate on other extension points that might be more useful? Basically, I need to implement something like the .Include method, but I need to change the behavior of the SQL join that EF creates.

Comment: @Ani I saw this, but I'm not sure how it helps me.  How could I implement Foo?  Following the example in that link, I don't understand why their QueryTranslator.Include is any different than just using the original .Include method directly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Disregard my comment about changing the behavior of the .Include method.  I restructured my data model so that this is unneccessary.  EF seems to work best if there are no complex behaviors on the joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) project, but instead of your method foo, You will be obliged to write expression tree which is equivalent.

Comment: Neat library - but all the examples show adding criteria to the where clause.  Can you provide an example that performs a projection in the select statement like my Foo would need to do?

Comment: Try this: Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> test = (x) => x; var result = context.Collection_Of_TEntity.AsExpandable().Select(x=> test.Invoke(x)).ToList();

Comment: This pretty much does what I originally asked.  Thanks!