# Intercept TSQL generated by linq before submitchanges method fire

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is possible intercept TSQL generated by linq before submitchanges() methods fire? I need modify sql insert query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap Entity Framework to intercept the LINQ expression just before execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839901/how-to-wrap-entity-framework-to-intercept-the-linq-expression-just-before-execut)

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is a very feature-limited ORM - I highly doubt there's anything in there that would allow you to modify the SQL....

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the SQL as such, but you *can* intercept the insertion process.  Your generated data context should have stubbed-out partial implementations of `Insert` mehods.  For example, if you entity is named, `MyDbEntity`:

```
partial void InsertMyDbEntity(MyDbEntity instance);
```

Since this is partial, you can modify it in the partial class that you've created around the generated data context.  You can then use this hook to either generate the INSERT statement out of whole cloth, or alternatively just call a custom stored procedure you've written to handle whatever nuance you're attempting to achieve.

This is the best you can do -- you can't instrument the existing INSERT SQL along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it is possible to intercept the `SubmitChanges()` call, but not the SQL itself.

In my application, my .dbml file is called "`GlobalPricing.dbml`", and I have created a class called `GlobalPricingDataContext.cs`.

```
public partial class GlobalPricingDataContext: System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    public override void SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
    {
        int inserts = base.GetChangeSet().Inserts.Count;
        int updates = base.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count;
        int deletes = base.GetChangeSet().Deletes.Count;

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  There are {1} inserts, {2} updates and {3} deletes.", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), inserts, updates, deletes)); 

        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);
    }
}
```

Again, this code won't let you modify the SQL which gets run, but it will at least let you know about what inserts, updates and deletes each of the `SubmitChanges()` calls is attempting to do.