# Intercept all EF6 Linq queries

Tags: linq, expression-trees, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I have a function which I want to run on every executed Linq query on a DbContext to modify the expression tree before execution.  I've been having a look at the IDbCommandTreeInterceptor interface but that doesn't seem to provide an expression tree (which I suppose is understandable since it may not have been a Linq query by the time it gets to this point).

Is there any way I can intercept and modify all expressions before execution?

nb. This has to be Linq tree modification because I have already built a framework for modifying Linq trees which was originally for Linq to SQL.

Comment: You may find some usefull info here (more in the question than in the answer for your problem) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839901/how-to-wrap-entity-framework-to-intercept-the-linq-expression-just-before-execut

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus that's not for EF6 - it was 2009

Comment: Yes, but IQueryable.Execute still exists...

Comment: it doesn't really help though unless there is a way of overriding the default provider now

Comment: Still looking for a better solution but did find this example ef 6.1.1 or above, https://github.com/rowanmiller/Demo-TechEd2014/blob/master/FakeEstate.ListingManager/Models/EFHelpers/SoftDeleteInterceptor.cs

Comment: The video for the presentation from where that code snippet comes is here http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid=. I think it's a pretty good option to go with!

Comment: It really needs to be a Linq tree though as I've already got a lot of code invested in modifying Linq trees

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating a proxy for the LINQ provider to intercept every LINQ expression execution (as suggested in the comments) is still a good solution. In fact, I'm playing around with this stuff [within this project](http://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq), which explicitly supports EF6 including EF6 async queries. You can create a standard .NET `ExpressionVisitor` to make an interception:

```
intercepted = query.Rewrite(new MyInterceptor());
```

But the question also demands "to run on *every* executed Linq query on a DbContext", and that will be the tricky part. One approach can be some kind of abstraction of `DbContext` / `DbSet`, so your code does not directly access `DbSet` objects. And inside the implementation of this abstraction the interception can happen...

Another approach (and I think that answers this question best) would be a proxy for `DbSet`, which calls the LINQ proxy for queries, which enables interception. First, we have to inherit from `DbSet`:

```
public class DbSetProxy<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>,
                                   IQueryable<TEntity>,
                                   IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> set;
    private readonly DbQuery<TEntity> query;

    private readonly IQueryable<TEntity> intercepted;

    public DbSetProxy(DbSet<TEntity> set)
        : this(set, set)
    {
    }

    public DbSetProxy(DbSet<TEntity> set, DbQuery<TEntity> query)
    {
        this.set = set;
        this.query = query;

        // use NeinLinq or any other LINQ proxy library
        intercepted = query.Rewrite(new MyInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Then, it's necessary to overwrite all the members to call the actual `DbSet` for non query stuff:

(**Note**: It's unfortunately necessary to overwrite every `DbSet` member, because inheriting `DbSet` is only designed for test stubs. Thus, just inheriting `DbSet` breaks the `DbSet`.)

```
public override DbQuery<TEntity> AsNoTracking()
{
    return new DbSetProxy<TEntity>(set, query.AsNoTracking());
}

public override DbQuery<TEntity> AsStreaming()
{
    return new DbSetProxy<TEntity>(set, query.AsStreaming());
}

public override DbQuery<TEntity> Include(string path)
{
    return new DbSetProxy<TEntity>(set, query.Include(path));
}

public override TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
{
    return set.Add(entity);
}

public override IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    return set.AddRange(entities);
}

public override TEntity Attach(TEntity entity)
{
    return set.Attach(entity);
}

public override TEntity Create()
{
    return set.Create();
}

public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
{
    return set.Create<TDerivedEntity>();
}

public override TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
{
    return set.Find(keyValues);
}

public override Task<TEntity> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
{
    return set.FindAsync(keyValues);
}

public override Task<TEntity> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues)
{
    return set.FindAsync(cancellationToken, keyValues);
}

public override TEntity Remove(TEntity entity)
{
    return set.Remove(entity);
}

public override IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    return set.RemoveRange(entities);
}

public override DbSqlQuery<TEntity> SqlQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    return set.SqlQuery(sql, parameters);
}

public override ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local
{
    get { return set.Local; }
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return set.Equals(obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return set.GetHashCode();
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return set.ToString();
}
```

Finally, we've to make use of the interception object:

```
IEnumerator<TEntity> IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return intercepted.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return intercepted.GetEnumerator();
}

Type IQueryable.ElementType
{
    get { return intercepted.ElementType; }
}

Expression IQueryable.Expression
{
    get { return intercepted.Expression; }
}

IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
{
    get { return intercepted.Provider; }
}

IDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity> IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
{
    return ((IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>)intercepted).GetAsyncEnumerator();
}

IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
{
    return ((IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>)intercepted).GetAsyncEnumerator();
}
```

And, at last, we can use an ordinary `DbContext`. We only have to overwrite its `Set` method to inject our proxy:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
    {
        return new DbSetProxy<TEntity>(base.Set<TEntity>());
    }
}
```

Comment: this intercepts too early in the Expression tree. I'm not so sure why this could answer to the OP's actual requirement? After accessing `DbSet`, you have ton of other building-blocks appended to build the final Expression tree before it being executed.
So at the point you intercepts it this way, you don't have the whole actual final Expression tree (to modify something).